# Kafka-to-Elasticsearch Data Transformation using Logstash Pipeline

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, apache-kafka, logstash, logstash-filter

Stack Overflow community,

I am currently working on a data processing pipeline where I receive data from Kafka in the following format:

```
{
  "id": "XYZ",
  "index": "original_data_index",
  "updated_data": {
    "id": "XYZ1",
    "index": "updated_data_index"
  }
}
```

My goal is to store the data in two separate Elasticsearch indices:

The original data should be stored in **index1** as:

```
{
  "id": "XYZ",
  "index": "original_data_index"
}
```

The updated data should be stored in **index2** as:

```
{
  "id": "XYZ1",
  "index": "updated_data_index"
}
```

I'm currently using Logstash as part of my pipeline, and I would like to know how I can achieve this transformation. Could someone provide guidance on configuring the Logstash pipeline to handle this specific data transformation scenario?

Additionally, if there are any best practices or considerations for handling Kafka data transformations with Logstash in the context of Elasticsearch indexing, I would appreciate any insights.

Thank you in advance for your help!

[Check out the diagram structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgWKd.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use pipeline-to-pipeline communication with a [forked path pattern](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/pipeline-to-pipeline.html#forked-path-pattern) to process the event in two different ways. In each path you can use a [prune](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-prune.html) filter or [mutate+remove_field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-remove_field) to remove the fields you do not want in the index that the path outputs to.